# Как создавать и изменять dbf в C#

Tags: c#, sql, odbc, dbf

Здравствуйте, нужно открыть dbf файл, изменить его через SQL запросы и сохранить в другой файл. С dbf никогда не работал, поэтому искал код в инете. Нашел вот такой код для чтения, который работает нормально:

```
OdbcConnection Conn = null;
...
string str = @"SELECT * FROM D:\Work\rrk.dbf";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(str, Conn);
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Но есть еще код для создания таблицы:

```
string str0 = "Create Table Persons (name char(20))";
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(str0, Conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Который выдает ошибку :"Для ExecuteNonQuery нужно открытое и доступное подключение Connection. Подключение закрыто.". 
Если добавить Conn.Open(); в начало и Conn.Close(); в конец, код исполняется (таблица видимо создается), но при последующем запуске происходит ошибка "таблица уже создана с таким именем".

```
 Conn.Open();
 string str0 = "Create table ass (name char(20))";
 OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(str0, Conn);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 Conn.Close();
```

Возникает сразу несколько вопросов: как сохранить созданную таблицу в dbf файл? Как сохранить ее в DataTable (для вывода затем в DataGridView)?

Comment: Есть много прекрасных готовых библиотек по работе с DBF, мне понравилась DotNetDBF

Answer (score 1):

вот нашел кусок кода для DotNetDBF :

```
using (Stream fos = File.Open(dbffile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                using (var writer = new DBFWriter())
                {         
                    writer.CharEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
                    writer.Signature = DBFSigniture.DBase3;
                    writer.LanguageDriver = 0x26; // кодировка 866
                    var field1 = new DBFField("DOCDATE", NativeDbType.Date);
                    var field2 = new DBFField("DOCNUMBER", NativeDbType.Char, 50);
                    var field3 = new DBFField("POSNAME", NativeDbType.Char, 255);
                    var field4 = new DBFField("POSCODE", NativeDbType.Numeric, 10, 0);
                    var field5 = new DBFField("RETPRICE", NativeDbType.Numeric, 10, 2);
                    var field6 = new DBFField("QUANTITY", NativeDbType.Numeric, 3, 2);
                    var field7 = new DBFField("APCODE", NativeDbType.Numeric, 10, 0);
                    var field8 = new DBFField("CLNTNAME", NativeDbType.Char, 255);
                    var field9 = new DBFField("CLNTPHONE", NativeDbType.Char, 20);

                    writer.Fields = new[] { field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9 };

                    foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                        writer.AddRecord(
                         // добавляем поля в набор
                            );
                    }
                    writer.Write(fos);
                }
```